# Getting cant call desiredCompressionMethod on an undefined value in Archive.pm at line 249

Tags: perl

I am trying to zip files with below code but getting this error "cant call desiredCompressionMethod  on an undefined value in Archive.pm at line 249". Below is my code. Please suggest.

```
    use Archive::Zip qw( :ERROR_CODES :CONSTANTS );

    my $zip = Archive::Zip->new();

    my $dir_member = $zip->addDirectory( 'D:\advapp\PSMAG\Scripts\Testing/' );
    my $file_member = $zip->addFile( 'xyz.txt', 'abc.txt' );
    unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed('someZip.zip') == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'write error';
    }

    my $somezip = Archive::Zip->new();
    unless ( $somezip->read( 'someZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'read error';
    }
    my $member = $somezip->memberNamed( 'stringMember.txt' );
    $member->desiredCompressionMethod( COMPRESSION_DEFLATED );
    unless ( $zip->writeToFileNamed( 'someOtherZip.zip' ) == AZ_OK ) {
    die 'write error';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a zip archive with two files:

> ```
> my $file_member = $zip->addFile( 'xyz.txt', 'abc.txt' );
> ```

Now you try to find a file called `stringMember.txt` in the same archive.

> ```
> my $member = $somezip->memberNamed( 'stringMember.txt' );
> ```

Obviously, that file does not exist, so [`memberNamed` returns `undef`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Archive::Zip#memberNamed-string) as it cannot find the file.

> Return ref to member whose filename equals given filename or undef. $string must be in Zip (Unix) filename format.

In consequence, you cannot call `desiredCompressionMethod` on that undefined value as the error message says.

---

If you copy the code from the documentation, make sure to either copy all of it, or change the parts to copy to fit your code.

Comment: even after removing this line i am getting same error.           my $member = $somezip->memberNamed( 'stringMember.txt' );

Comment: @sur If you remove that line, `$member` is **not declared** at all. Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place? You can **only do something** on `$member` if it is _declared and contains the Zip::Archive member whatever object_.

Comment: Hi simbabque, considering the fact you said that line is returning undef i have added the modified it to the file name which is present, still receiving the same error. I am kind of new to perl, kindly let me know where am going wrong.

Comment: I am not familiar with Archive::Zip I'm afraid. There is a method `memberNames` that should return all file names in the archive. Call that one and use Data::Dumper or Data::Printer to check. Then take it from there.